# PhantomJS cannot click on existing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, phantomjs, dispatchevent

I use PhantomJS 1.9.7 on windows 8.1 and I am going to click on Login button after typing username and password. I can write username and password but, when I want PhantomJS to click on the button, It can find the element but is not able of clicking on that. 
I found in previous posts that I need to create event and use "dispatchEvent". I did that but I got an error as follows:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elm.dispatchEvent(event)')

I also tried to get help from EventListener but I got the same error for that.

How can I click on an element?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('URL', function() {
    var submitButton = enterUserAndPassAndLogin();      
    click(submitButton);
    phantom.exit();
});

function enterUserAndPassAndLogin() {
    var element = page.evaluate(function()  {
        document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value = "*******";
        document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value = "*******";
        return document.getElementsByTagName("Button");
    });
    return element;
}

function click(elm) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    elm.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Can you write the code you are using to click the button?

Comment: @cracker: please don't use [inline code spans for highlighting words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) -- it's often not necessary and if something really requires emphasis, please [use bold or italics](http://www.etf.europa.eu/authorssite.nsf/Pages/Use%20of%20bold%20and%20italics) instead. Inline code spans are (as the name implies) for code within sentences only: please keep this in mind when editing posts.

Comment: Sure, thanks i'll  take care next time

Comment: I have added my code to the above post. is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the code. First DOM elements cannot be passed from the page context (`page.evaluate`) outside. Corresponding line from the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!

So the `submitButton` is `[null]`. Because an array is returned, the error message doesn't show the actual problem. Since the DOM element cannot be passed outside, the click must happen inside of `page.evaluate`.

Since `page.evaluate` is sandboxed the `click` function must be defined inside of the page context. Variables and functions from outside cannot be directly accessed.

A possible script is this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('URL', function() {
    enterUserAndPassAndLogin();
    setTimeout(function(){
        // wait a little to maybe see the click result
        phantom.exit();
    }, 1000);
});

function enterUserAndPassAndLogin() {
    page.evaluate(function()  {
        function click(elm) {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            elm.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        document.querySelector('input[name="username"]').value = "*******";
        document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value = "*******";
        click(document.getElementsByTagName("Button")[0]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply plug in Jquery and do

```
$(selector).trigger('click');
```

Note, that if the page uses an async post, the page load event does not trigger, however it "is loading" and you have to wait for the response.

maybe set a wait for a few secs and that will simply be enough for the async post to come back.

Comment: Just suggesting "Do it with jQuery instead!" does nothing to solve the specific issue that the OP is having.

Comment: Dear @sphanley: Just to note: the poster says: dispatchEvent was undefined. Jquery has the method. For sure.

Comment: Yeah, but that's like telling someone who's asking for help with getting their car to start to just take the bus instead. Sure, jQuery can trigger a click on an element, but the OP is using PhantomJS, not jQuery.